# CKEditor Remove Extra Lines

Tags: html, ckeditor, code-formatting

CKEDitor has been giving me some issues

When I'm trying to add

```
<p>This is a sample</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
   <li>Example 1</li>
   <li>Example 2</li>
</ul>
```

it adds an extra line for no reason

```
<p>
   This is a sample</p>
<p>
   &nbsp;</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      Example 1</li>
   <li>
      Example 2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting , especially the part about "breakAfterOpen".

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
    {
        on :
        {
            instanceReady : function( ev )
            {
                // Output paragraphs as <p>Text</p>.
                this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
                    {
                        indent : false,
                        breakBeforeOpen : true,
                        breakAfterOpen : false,
                        breakBeforeClose : false,
                        breakAfterClose : true
                    });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I looked at that but where do you enter that code? I'm really confused on that.

Comment: You should do it when you create the CKEditor object. Exactly how you do it depends on exactly how you're creating it, I believe.